# How to send event as argument to a angular function when using maplibre?

Tags: angular, mapbox, ngrx, maplibre-gl

how to do it in angular, primarly how to catch an moveend event in angular using maplibre and send it to a function as argument
code in component.html

```
<mgl-map [center]="initialCenter" [zoom]="[initialZoom]" (load)="loadMap($event)" [style]="'assets/map.style.json'"
  (moveEnd)="updateMap($event)">
```

This above code is written using mapbox and I need to implement this in maplibre, the event has to be sent to updateMap() method in component in order for it to work.
component.ts

```
  updateMap(event: { target: Map }) {
    console.log('event', event);
    const { target } = event;
  

    this.mapFacade.mapChanged(
      target.getBounds(),
      target.getCenter(),
      target.getZoom()
    );
  }
```

Using Maplibre I am not able to send the event to upadateMap. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is link to app done using mapbox but I have to implement app using maplibre.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-mapbox-demo?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts&view=preview

Comment: when map move then it is firing updateMap function.

Comment: Yes , stackblitz example , ngx wrapper is used but for me in maplibre I don't have things working as expected as we have to write /initiate inside ngafterViewInit

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Documentation has only Javascript examples but I had to implement in Typescript inside angular complying to ngrx store so I figured out a hack. Js code doesn't understands 'this' in local scope of a function so I did this.

Code inside ngAfterViewInit():

```
 var a = { lng: 77.1025, lat: 28.7041, zoom: 4 }
 this.map = new Map({
      container: this.mapContainer.nativeElement,
      style: `https://api.maptiler.com/maps/eef16200-c4cc-4285-9370-c71ca24bb42d/style.json?key=Key_Please!`,
      // style: './../../../assets/map.style.json',
      center: a,
      zoom: a.zoom,
      hash: true,
    });

function value(){
    var aa=amap.on("moveend", function(e){
      return e;
    })
    return {"target":aa};
  }
    var ee= value();
    this.updateMap(ee);
```

Code outside, which I wanted to send an argument in order to make the ngrx store get working in sync.

```
  updateMap(event: { target: Map }) {
    const { target } =  event;
   
    this.mapFacade.mapChanged(
      target.getBounds(),
      target.getCenter(),
      target.getZoom()
    );
  }
```

And this is how the html code will be in Angular:[ for maplibre-js]

```
<div class="map" #map>
        <a href="https://www.maptiler.com" class="watermark"><img src="https://api.maptiler.com/resources/logo.svg"
                alt="MapTiler logo" /></a>
        
    </div>
```

You can get more clarity on this by reaching the code over here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-mapbox-demo?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts&view=preview which I tried to implement usinng maplibre instead of using ngx wrapper used in link mentioned .